# Generating more than one file with one rule- Makefile

Tags: makefile

I apologise if this question was already asked before, I researched and couldn't find an appropriate answer.

I have a C++ project that I have to compile using make.

The output that I want, is three different executables using one make file, but I have to compile it using a Pattern Rule.

The project consists of three source files for each executable, all of them use a function from a header file that I compile into an object file.

I have managed to compile them all, but using a seperate rule for each file

An example of one rule:

```
file1: file1.cpp header.o header.h
      g++ $(FLAGS) file1.cpp header.o -o file1
```

Thanks.

Edit:

```
file1: file1.cpp header.o header.h
  g++ $(FLAGS) file1.cpp header.o -o file1

file2: file2.cpp header.o header.h
  g++ $(FLAGS) file2.cpp header.o -o file2

file3: file3.cpp header.o header.h
  g++ $(FLAGS) file3.cpp header.o -o file3
```

These are the executables

```
header.o: header.cpp header.h
      g++ $(FLAGS) -c header.cpp -o header.o
```

And this is the object file with the function

FLAGS variable includes the directory where the header files are stored.

Comment: Why does `file1` depend on both `header.o` and `header.h`? Why are you compiling headers separately in the first place? In any case if the `file1: file1.cpp` pattern holds for each executable then you won't even need a single recipe, post a [mcve].

Comment: Hello, I edited the main post and included all the code that I have. I am compiling the header files to object code to then link it to each executable.

Comment: That still isn't an mcve, what is `FLAGS` set to? The reason I mentioned `header.o` is that you **never** compile headers separately (except when using things like precompiled headers, which you aren't here), they are `include`d in other translation units.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice the "FLAGS variable includes the directory where the header files are stored.", you should add that to the makefile content exactly as it's used.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly and I apologise if I wasn't clear about this. I compile the sourcefile that includes the function into an object file that I then link with the executables.

Comment: I made the mistake in the object file rule and corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

Make has [built-in rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) for compiling and linking, all you need to do is use the correct format for your variables and rules, the following should work

```
targets  := file1 file2 file3
CPPFLAGS := -Isome_include_dir

.PHONY: all 
all: $(targets)
$(targets): CC := $(CXX)
$(targets): %: %.o header.o
%.o: header.h
```

Comment: Yes! This has solved my problem. I was thinking about using this but wasn't sure how, I got it working now. Thanks. I'll see if I can give you a +1, since I'm a new user. If not then I'm sorry. Thanks again!